# Hbase filter to find rows without a specific column

Tags: filter, hbase, comparator

I want to filter out all rows that do not have a specific column. any idea which comparator to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [skip filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SkipFilter.html) combined with [qualifier filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/QualifierFilter.html). 
If you use the java client API:

```
Filter filter = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("column-name")));
Filter filter2 = new SkipFilter(filter);
scan.setFilter(filter2);
```

this will return all the row without that specific column

Answer (score 0):

SingleColumnValueFilter has method `setFilterIfMissing` that excludes all row that do not contain given column if it is given `true`. All that is needed is to design filter so it will always pass and call `setFilterIfMissing(true)`

```
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new  SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes("column_name"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("non-sense"));
    filter.setFilterIfMissing(true);
    scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".